# Loading packery.js with RequireJS

Tags: requirejs, amd

I am struggling to load packery.js with require.js. The script is been loaded but I am getting the following error in the console, even if packery is not initialized on the page.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined : packery.pkgd.js:486**

And 486th row is this:

```
    var EventEmitter = window.EventEmitter;
    for ( var prop in EventEmitter.prototype ) {
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
      docReady[ prop ] = EventEmitter.prototype[ prop ];
    }
```

That's the latest version of packery which i've just downloaded from the github.
Anyone experiencing the same issue? Thanks...

Comment: How are you loading it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to load:

1) define a path to your script:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
    .....
    "jquery" : "path/to/jquery.js"
    "packery" : "path/to/packery.js"
    .....
}
```

2) define dependencies in shim section

```
shim:{
    "packery" : ["jquery"] 
}
```

3) Include library in module dependencies array and use it on callback

```
define(
    [
        "jquery",
        "packery"
    ],
    function($){
        $('.some').packery
    }
);
```